# Не получается собрать Python 3.7 из официальных исходников. Ошибка: No module named '_ctypes'

Tags: python, ubuntu, сборка, makefile, build-error

Всем добра и привет! Хочу себе поставить "Змею" поновее, а именно 3.7 ([т.к. кое-кто из семейства оконных не хочет работать](https://toster.ru/q/543379)). Скачиваю сначала исходники с сайта, делаю `sudo make altinstall` и тут ошибка.

Бегу на [официальные доки](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/unix.html#building-python), качаю [CPython с GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.7), компилю, и на том же моменте та же самая ошибка. Что делать (подскажите пжлст)?

Ой, вот ошибка:

```
running install_scripts
copying build/scripts-3.7/idle3.7 -> /usr/local/bin
copying build/scripts-3.7/pydoc3.7 -> /usr/local/bin
copying build/scripts-3.7/pyvenv-3.7 -> /usr/local/bin
copying build/scripts-3.7/2to3-3.7 -> /usr/local/bin
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/idle3.7 to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/pydoc3.7 to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/pyvenv-3.7 to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/2to3-3.7 to 755
rm /usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sysconfigdata_m_linux_x86_64-linux-gnu.py
rm -r /usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/__pycache__
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Misc/python.man \
    /usr/local/share/man/man1/python3.7.1
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
    case upgrade in \
        upgrade) ensurepip="--altinstall --upgrade" ;; \
        install|*) ensurepip="--altinstall" ;; \
    esac; \
     ./python -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timosha/cpython-3.7/Lib/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/timosha/cpython-3.7/Lib/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/timosha/cpython-3.7/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "/home/timosha/cpython-3.7/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 204, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/home/timosha/cpython-3.7/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 117, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/home/timosha/cpython-3.7/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 27, in _run_pip
    import pip._internal
  File "/tmp/tmpv8cl2p7b/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpv8cl2p7b/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpv8cl2p7b/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpv8cl2p7b/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/download.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpv8cl2p7b/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/utils/glibc.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/timosha/cpython-3.7/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
Makefile:1132: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «altinstall»
make: *** [altinstall] Ошибка 1
```

***P.S.:*** Все команды выполнялись от имени root'а (sudo) *-| Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS |-*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Существует [соответствующий "баг" со статусом [open] - `"make install fails: no module _ctypes"`](https://bugs.python.org/issue31652).

Причина возникновения ошибки - отсутствие установленного пакета `libffi(-dev[el])`.

Соответственно надо попробовать его установить перед сборкой Python 3.7.

В качестве альтернативного варианта предлагают сконфигурировать Python перед сборкой следующим образом:

```
configure --without-ensurepip
```

Comment: команда для установки на Ubuntu 16.04: `sudo apt install libffi-dev`

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/544484 - тут ещё ответы)